# How hidden children element of parent with JS ? (or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to hide the `<div id='coco'>` present in the `<div id='altOcr'>` with JS or JQuery.

Here is my base code:

```
<div id='altOcr'>
    <div id='coco'>abc</div>
    <div id='coco'>def</div>
</div>
<div id='altOcr'>
    <div id='coco'>abc</div>
    <div id='coco'>def</div>
</div>
```

I've been browsing the forum a bit, testing solutions, but it didn't work for me. At least I can not HIDDEN the selected element.

```
document.getElementById('coco').altOcrNone.style.display='none';
```

But this code gives me an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'style')

Comment: _"Here is my base code:"_ - faulty to begin with; IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. An `id` must be **unique** within a document. Then look at `getElementsbyClassName`

Comment: The `id` attribute must be unique. You should use `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// select all alt0cr divs

const allaltOcr = document.querySelectorAll("#altOcr");


// looping through each div and selecting children to set siplay property. It is not very efficent, but might work for you!

allaltOcr.forEach((e) => {
  const children = e.querySelectorAll("#coco");
  children.forEach(e => { 
   e.style = "display: none"
  })
});
```

```html
<div id='altOcr'>
    <div id='coco'>abc</div>
    <div id='coco'>def</div>
</div>
<div id='altOcr'>
    <div id='coco'>abc</div>
    <div id='coco'>def</div>
</div>
<div id='coco'>STILL HERE :)</div>
```

Comment: Because an id must be unique, you could much more simply use `e.querySelector('#coco')` as then you do do not have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

var hideElement = document.getElementById('coco');

hideElement.style.display='none';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).